# Where should color codes be stored?

Tags: android, colors

We put strings in string.xml, dimension in dimens.xml, but what about color codes?
Should they be moved in string.xml or should you create a new drawable file for that?
Which is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the colors.xml file in the res/value folder of your project, like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="welcome_page">#C68632</color>
    <color name="profile_page">#CDB135</color>
    <color name="galery_page">#64B555</color>
    <color name="exit_page">#00A2A4</color>
</resources>
```

Then you can use for example android:textColor="@color/galery_page"

Answer (score 1):

Make a file called colors.xml just like we make string.xml and dimens.xml in res/values/

```
    .....
    <color name="safe_mode_text">#80ffffff</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="black">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
    <color name="background_dark">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="background_light">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_dark">@android:color/background_light</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_light">@android:color/background_dark</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_dark_disabled">#80ffffff</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_light_disabled">#80000000</color>
    .....
```

[From android source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/colors.xml)

Answer (score 1):

I would store them in res/values/colours.xml

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Note that you can name the XML file whatever you want (e.g. color/colour..), as long as the XML inside it is structured correctly, it will work and it will appear in your generated resources